# How does MMR work in normals?

Tags: league-of-legends

I sometimes play with my friends and our ranks are:

**normally 1 Gold (me), 1 Diamond, 1 Platinum and 2 Silver.**

We often get teams with one solo player (not premade with the others) that is unranked or low bronze) and he gets absolutely destroyed.

**How does our MMR from Rankeds come into play in Normals?**

**Does it come into play at all? Do we have different MMR for Normals/Rankeds?**

**Is it just random?**

Comment: What do you mean by 'normal'? (Normal Matchmaking?)

Comment: @aytimothy normal = not-ranked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In League of Legends, there are seperate Elo scores for each gamemode's matchmaking. This means that your ranked Elo is seperate to your standard (normal game) Elo.

When going into Matchmaking, the matchmaking system uses the Elo **that corresponds to the gamemode you're queuing for**.
Because Ranked games and standard games are considered two different gamemodes, they have two different scores.

(ie. You have 1000 Elo (it's an estimate, we don't actually get to see this value) in standard games, and 3000 Elo (this value is visable in your Ranked stats) for ranked games on Summoner's Rift. *This means that your next standard game will be against those that have a lower skill-level than you, while your next ranked game will be against those that are the same skill-level as you.*)

### As far as the matchmaking system is concerned: Your ranked Elo (MMR) does not affect  the standard Elo (isn't taken into consideration during Standard Game matchmaking).

The point is: Even if you're the top player in Ranked games, and you've never played a single standard game (not possible, since you HAVE to play Standard Games to be able to level up), you will be matched with those close to the starting Elo if you were to play a Standard non-ranked match. **The matchmaking system does NOT care about your ranked stats (MMR, Elo, etc.) if you queue for a Standard non-ranked game.**

The only thing that will be taken into consideration is your loading screen portrait, which reflects the current league you're in.

Comment: "You have your MMR, which is visible to anyone and is used when matching in ranked games." The MMR is not visible, the Elo ranking is.

Comment: @Shunwoo dont agree.... MMR can be calculated and is "visible" via op.gg

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW I might be wrong on that but op.gg isn't affiliated to Riot, and you have no Riot ways to see your MMR, all they want you to see is your Elo. MMR is supposed to be hidden, like in starcraft for example.

Comment: @Shunwoo and where do you see the ELO?! it definitly not league/division/LP. Elo is the old system for that and not being used anymore. somepeople still use it as a synonym.

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW Well in s1 / s2, Elo was the value shown to the players, determining your league depending on your points (categories are shown in aytimothy's link) but there already was a MMR at this time. And the actual League/division/LP system is what replaced the old Elo interface, adding the harder to cross "borders" between leagues and division.
And simply put, the variation on your Elo (or LP now) depends is higher when the difference between your MMR and Elo rating is bigger.

Comment: The term 'MMR' is just a "synonym" of Elo. It's still a value that determines your level of skill.

Comment: @aytimothy no. you're MMR will rise much faster than your LP when your on a winstreak. thats why its possible to skip divisions.

Comment: The Elo system is composed off a value (old Elo shown or LP now) and a MMR. The first one is your total of points determining your ranking, it moves rather slowly, whereas MMR varies heavily with win streaks (or lose streaks). It's actually the difference of values between the two that determines your gain or loss of LP no?

Comment: @Shunwoo no. its not simple as that.

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW of course it's not just a "MMR - Elo" formula, I'm talking about the idea. The formulas behind are a bit indigest ^^

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW I just wanted to add that the old Elo points shown are now the LP/divison thing, and MMR was hidden back then, and still is now. You can only access it by the mean of third-parties programs/websites, that are not from Riot company.

Comment: MMR is indeed not visible, Riot makes it explicitly impossible to find. Places like op.gg merely try to guess what the hidden MMR is. Exactly how Riot calculates Elo is not known but is speculated in many places, including here: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Elo_rating_system#Calculating_Elo

Answer (score 1):

You have a MMR for each different queue: normal 5, normal 3, aram, dominion, ranked 5, team ranked 5, team ranked 3, and I believe team builder also has a separate number.

So when you queue up with your friend, the game takes the average MMR of your team, and matches it against another team with the same average MMR. If your players haven't played a lot of normals, your MMR won't be high and you'll be matched against lower level players, or players having played as few games as you. If you keep playing normals, you'll end up playing against better and better players, as your MMR rises.

The only place where your MMR from other queues is taken into account is when you're playing team ranked 5/3. IE, a team of 5 bronze players having never played ranked team and going 5-0 in placement will be placed in silver, wile a team full of diamonds having never played ranked teams and going 5-0 will be placed in gold.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure how it works, but I have a theory:

The matchmaking for rankeds tries longer to match the same MMR of each member. (Thats why high elo players have really long queue times for rankeds)

The matchmaking for normals just gets a bunch of people that just queued up and trys to even out the average MMR of the teams. This way you wont have long queue times. Premade teams also "increase" the MMR for this specific match.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be confusion between MMR and ELO as I am reading in the comments. Look up what ELO is, it's a number that determines your relative skill level. This system has been in place for competitive games for a long, long time. In League, there was a time that it was shown, and now it's not. ELO = MMR (Match Making Rating). Your Match Making Rating is a number that (surprise) shows your relative skill level! They are synonyms. LP is different. There is NO WAY to know your TRUE ELO/MMR. Sites like na.op.gg, as someone mentioned, is NOT affiliated with RIOT. They calculate an ELO/MMR with THEIR OWN ALGORITHM. Regardless of how ACCURATE it is, it is not official.